# How are multiple message types facilitated through a single connection with 0MQ?

Tags: zeromq

With RabbitMq, subscriptions to multiple queues are achieved over a single connection via Channels.  This allows a single socket to be used to process multiple subscriptions.  What is the analog strategy for minimizing socket connections for multiple message types in Zero MQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say PUB/SUB message envelopes is the preferred way to solve this problem in ZeroMQ (see [Pub-Sub Message Envelopes](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc49)).

Before sending a message, the publisher should send its topic in the envelope:

```
    s_sendmore (publisher, "A");
    s_send (publisher, <Serialized MessageA>);
    .....
    s_sendmore (publisher, "B");
    s_send (publisher, <Serialized MessageB>);
```

Suscriber has 3 options to handle multiple topics:

[image: Figure 1]

- Read the message type from the envelope, use a deserializer depending on message type (Client 1 on the figure).

  ```
  char *topic = s_recv (subscriber);
  char *body = s_recv (subscriber);
  //If topic == "A", the body contains serialized MessageA, otherwise MessageB
  ```
- Subscribe only to a single topic with `zmq_setsockopt (subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, ...);`. In this situation ZeroMQ performs PUB-side message filtering (since 3.x), and the client can be sure that it will only receive messages of type MessageA (Client 2 on the figure)

  ```
  char *topic = s_recv (subscriber);
  char *body = s_recv (subscriber);
  //Ignore the topic, the body contains serialized MessageA
  ```
- Subscribe to all messages and create a proxy within the client process that publishes messages on `INPROC` sockets. Individual subscribers should use `zmq_setsockopt (subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, ...);` to subscribe to the messages of single type. (see Client 3).

  ```
  void *frontend = zsocket_new (context, ZMQ_SUB);
  zsocket_connect (frontend, "tcp://<....>");
  void *backend = zsocket_new (context, ZMQ_PUB);
  zsocket_bind (backend, "inproc://all_messages");
  //  Start the proxy
  zmq_proxy (frontend, backend, NULL);
  ...
  //On another thread
  void *sub1 = zsocket_new (context, ZMQ_SUB);
  zsocket_connect (sub1, "inproc://all_messages");
  zmq_setsockopt (subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "A", 1);
  ...
  void *sub2 = zsocket_new (context, ZMQ_SUB);
  zsocket_connect (sub2, "inproc://all_messages");
  zmq_setsockopt (subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "B", 1);
  ```

You may also find useful XPUB/XSUB sockets for various tricks. See for example 
[Last Value Caching](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Last-Value-Caching)

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  Is there a way to achieve this behavior with Request/Response?

Comment: @DerekGreer Topic filtering is only available for SUB sockets, so only option #1 will work. I'd say that RPC pattern is more natural for REQ/REP sockets. And it's possible to use one of serialization frameworks for RPC protocol layer, using ZeroMQ as a transport. For example, take a look on my ThriftZMQ project on GitHub: https://github.com/thriftzmq/thriftzmq-java